# can we access the autolock setting that the user has set in iOS?

Tags: ios, settings, python-idle, auto-lock

I just want to find out what the user has set for the timeout period for autolock, which is in Settings->General->Auto-Lock in iOS.  How can I find this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Actually, just found out from apple...there is no public API for this.